# What is the Clifford/geometric product in terms of the inner and exterior product

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, clifford-algebras

The geometric product is defined generally as the algebra on the space of multivectors $\bigwedge \Lambda(V)$

$$ab = a \cdot b + a \wedge b$$

with $\cdot$ a product on the vector space $V$ and $\wedge$ the exterior product. But how do those definitions extend to general multivectors? That is, for the multivectors

\begin{eqnarray}
A_i \in \Lambda^i V,\ A &=& \sum_{i=0}^n a_i A_i\\
B_i \in \Lambda^i V,\ B &=& \sum_{i=0}^n b_i B_i
\end{eqnarray}

What are the products $A \cdot B$ and $A \wedge B$? For the exterior product I'm guessing it will simply be

$$A \wedge B = (\sum_{i=0}^n a_i A_i) \wedge (\sum_{j=0}^n b_j B_j)$$

since that is a well defined quantity, but in the case of the inner product, it seems a bit harder. From some books it seems to be something of the form of the sum over every combination of the basis contracting with each other, for instance,

$$e_1 \cdot (e_2 \wedge e_3) = \frac 12 \left[(e_1 \cdot e_2) e_3 + (e_1 \cdot e_3) e_2 \right]$$

which maps $n$-blades to $(n-1)$-blades, with the appropriate generalization for inhomogeneous multivectors and arbitrary $n$-blades, although I'm not sure how the inner product of two $2$-blades work, either, or what happens in the case of $0$-forms, is it simply the product in this case? Is this the correct product, and in particular, is there a definition of it that is independant of the choice of basis?

Answer (score 2):

> The geometric product is defined generally as the algebra on the space of multivectors $\bigwedge \Lambda(V)$
>   $ab = a \cdot b + a \wedge b$

I'm not sure what you're reading, and that's not surprising given the disparate descriptions available, but I don't think I have ever seen the geometric product defined *in terms of this identity*.  In most places, you see the geometric product defined on the product of chosen orthonormal basis vectors, extended linearly. Then $\wedge$ is defined and it is shown that $ab = a \cdot b + a \wedge b$ follows.

I don't think a single description of the geometric product on the entire algebra in terms of $\cdot$ and $\wedge$ exists. This is mainly because of what you mention next:

> What are the products $A \cdot B$ and $A \wedge B$?

The dot and wedge products are not defined for general elements ([there are many useful extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_algebra#Extensions_of_the_inner_and_exterior_products)). Describing everything in terms of $\cdot$ and $\wedge$ would require that.

If we viewed the geometric algebra as the quotient of the tensor algebra $T(V)$ by the ideal generated by $v\otimes v-v\cdot v$, this would amount to asking for a general form of the product of two arbitrary elements in terms of this quotient, and that seems too messy to have a simple answer.

The lesson should be that a lot of geometric algebra hype gets one's hopes up in terms of simple explanations and tidy expressions. While this is true in a lot of places, it doesn't seem to be true in this situation. Not in the "basic" geometric algebra at least. A lot of advances have been made by embedding geometric structures in larger versions of the algebra, so perhaps there is something more appealing there.

Comment: One source I found (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.5935.pdf) defined the inner product in term of the Clifford product as $$A \cdot B = \sum_{r,s} \langle A_r B_s \rangle_{s-r}$$though it's not quite clear what this means from the point of view of the components

Comment: @Slereah That's among the list of alterantive extensions listed in the link I gave.

Answer (score 1):

$
\newcommand\grade[1]{\langle#1\rangle}
\newcommand\lcontr{{\rfloor}}
\newcommand\rcontr{{\lfloor}}
$

## The Exterior Product

Given multivectors $A = \sum_{i=0}^n A_i$ and $B = \sum_{i=0}^n B_i$ where $A_i, B_i$ are $i$-vectors, then since $\wedge$ is bilinear
$$
  A\wedge B = \sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^n A_i\wedge B_j.
$$
To define $\wedge$ in terms of the geometric product, typically we'd go with
$$
  A_i\wedge B_j = \grade{A_iB_j}_{i+j}
$$
where $\grade{}_k$ is the projection onto the grade $k$ part; then you extend by linearity, meaning
$$
  A\wedge B = \sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^n\grade{A_iB_j}_{i+j}.
$$
If $a_1, a_2,\dotsc, a_k$ are vectors, then we can also define their exterior product as the completely antisymmetrized sum:
$$
  a_1\wedge a_2\wedge\cdots\wedge a_k = \frac1{k!}\sum_{\sigma\in\mathrm{Perm}(k)}\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)a_{\sigma(1)}a_{\sigma(2)}\cdots a_{\sigma(k)},
$$
where the summation is over all permutations of $\{1,\dotsc,k\}$. You can probably extend this to blades, but I don't know how off the top of my head.

## The Inner Product

Rather than trying to work with some sort of symmetric dot product, it is much better to work with the *left ($\lcontr$)* and *right ($\rcontr$) contractions*. See [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4612-0089-5_2). These are most naturally defined as the operations *adjoint* to the exterior product:
$$
  \grade{(A\wedge B)C}_0 = \grade{A(B\lcontr C)}_0,\quad
  \grade{A(B\wedge V)}_0 = \grade{(A\rcontr B)C}_0
$$
for arbitrary multivectors $A, B, C$. There are also the *universal* identities
$$
  (A\wedge B)\lcontr C = A\lcontr(B\lcontr C),\quad
  A\rcontr(B\wedge C) = (A\rcontr B)\rcontr C.
$$
As you may have gotten a sense for, the left and right contractions have the same identities but reversed; as such, I'll just focus on the left contraction from now on.

On vectors, we simply have $a\lcontr b = a\cdot b$. Contraction by a vector is a (graded) *derivation*:
$$
  a\lcontr(B\wedge C) = (a\lcontr B)\wedge C + \hat B\wedge(a\lcontr C)
$$
where $\hat B$ is the grade involution (or main involution) of $B$.

In general, we can find that
$$
  A_i\lcontr B_j = \begin{cases}
    0 &\text{if } j - i < 0 \\
    \grade{A_iB_j}_{j-i} &\text{if } j - i \geq 0.
\end{cases}
$$
Extending by linearity to general multivectors $A = \sum_{i=0}^nA_i$ and $B = \sum_{i=0}^nB_i$,
$$
  A\lcontr B = \sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^nA_i\lcontr B_j
  = \sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^n\grade{A_iB_j}_{j-i},
$$
with the convention that $\grade{\cdots}_{j-i} = 0$ if $j - i < 0$.

On blades $A_i, B_j$, the contraction has a geometric interpretation: $A_i\lcontr B_j = 0$ if and only if $i > j$ or there is a vector in $A_i$ completely perpendicular $B_j$. When it is not zero, $A_i\lcontr B_j$ is a subblade of $B_j$ completely perpendicular to $A_i$.

## The Geometric Product

There is not a simple way (I know of) to express the geometric product of arbitrary multivectors in terms of contraction and exterior product. That being said, for $a$ a vector and $B$ an arbitrary multivector, we do have
$$
  aB = a\lcontr + a\wedge B,\quad Ba = B\rcontr a + B\wedge a.
$$